# React Native change variable after update

Tags: react-native, real-time-updates

I am new on the React-Native and I am trying to get array count after add something.When I change the tab I get it but I want to get after add something. By the way I want to write in as "tabBarBadge".

Comment: If I am getting this correct, you want the state to update so something like. I have the number "0" and when I click on a button to add "+1" to the state it will update and show the number "1" instead of the number "0" without you refreshing the screen right ?

Comment: Yes you are right. This will be ecommerce app. I use mobx with observable and inject. I update variable in detail page after redirect to main page but cart doesn't update.

Comment: You can achieve this by storing the value in local storage. Ideal is to use redux store. are you using redux in your application?

Comment: you must use a **state manager**. you can use **redux** or **context api**, I recommended to you use context api

Comment: Thank you for your all replies. I started use redux.